# How to use named destination for custom processor in spring cloud data flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am learning SCDF these days...I hava some questions about named destination.
I create a stream like ":test-topic > log". I can see the log sink consume data from topic "test-topic".
But if I add a custom processor to SCDF.Then I create a stream like this:

:test-topic-source > etl-data-transform > :test-topic-sink

I think the "etl-data-transform" processor will consume data from topic "test-topic-source"(Kafka) and product data to "test-topic-sink", but the log is "Subscribed to topic(s): stringOperation-in-0" and "Using kafka topic for outbound: stringOperation-out-0" ("stringOperation" is my custom function)

Why SCDF do not use the topic "test-topic-source" and "test-topic-sink"?
How to solve it?

---

I know I can use properties like this:
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.stringOperation-in-0=in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.in.destination=test-topic-source
but if I want to output to two topics?

Thanks!

Comment: Thx! That is my mistake. I add '@EnableBinding(Processor.class)' to my custom processor and then fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your custom processor application uses the `inbound` and `outbound` names to be `in` and `out`. The SCDF expects these names to be `input` and `output` respectively. This is the reason you see the explicit binding names based on the names `in` and `out`. Please change the names to be `input` and `output` and I believe that should fix this issue.

Comment: Thx! That is my mistake. I add '@EnableBinding(Processor.class)' to my custom processor and then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thx! That is my mistake. I add '@EnableBinding(Processor.class)' to my custom processor and then fix it.